# How to do it by using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

help please to do standart slider view [like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDwwi.jpg) without changing HTML. If it's impossible with flex, maybe with another properties, but class "dots" shouldn't be outside slider block.

```
<div id="slider">
 <div class="arrowLeft"><</div>
 <div class="window"></div>
 <div class="arrowRight">></div>
 <div class="dots">....</div>
</div>

#slider {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.window {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: The most close I found it's it:
`.arrowLeft, .arrowRight, .window {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}`
But it isn't correct because of arrows become in center of blocks. I didn't find anything else. That's why I am here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  /* font-size can effect single white space including line breaks - set individually */
  margin:0; padding:0; font-size:0;
}
#html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#333;
}
#slider,.arrow,.arrow>div,.dots{
  display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;
}
#slider{
  flex-wrap:wrap; width:100%; background:skyblue; padding:20px 10px;
}
#slider>div{
  height:100%;
}
.arrow{
  width:50px;
}
#slider>.window{
  width:calc(100% - 100px); height:150px; background:#fff;
}
.arrow>div{
  width:24px; height:24px; background:#eee; border-radius:50%;
}
.arrow>div>div{
  width:10px; height:10px; border:4px solid skyblue; transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.arrowLeft>div>div{
  border-top:0; border-right:0;
}
.arrowRight>div>div{
  border-bottom:0; border-left:0;
}
#slider>.dots{
  width:100%; height:20px; color:#fff; font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='slider'>
    <div class='arrow arrowLeft'><div><div></div></div></div>
    <div class='window'></div>
    <div class='arrow arrowRight'><div><div></div></div></div>
    <div class='dots'>....</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```